# How Match a Pattern in Text using Scanner and Pattern Classes?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

i want to find whether a particular pattern exists in my text file or not.

i m using following classes for this :

```
java.util.regex.Pattern and java.util.Scanner;
```

my sample text Line is

```
String Line="DBREF  1A1F A  102   190  UNP    P08046   EGR1_MOUSE     308    396";
```

and, i want to match following kind of pattern :

```
A    102   190
```

where, at A's position a-z or A-Z but single charter.

at 102's position any integer and of any length.

at 190's position any integer and of any length.

and,My code for pattern matching is:

```
     Scanner sr=new Scanner(Line);
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+([a-zA-Z]){1}\\s+\\d{1,}\\s+\\d{1,}\\s+");
     while(sr.hasNext(p))
     {
         System.out.println("Pattern exists");
         System.out.println("Matched String : "+sr.next(p));
     }
```

but,
     pattern is not matching even it exist there..

i think the problem is with my pattern string :

```
\\s+([a-zA-Z]){1}\\s+\\d{1,}\\s+\\d{1,}\\s+"
```

anybody, Plz help me what pattern string should i use????

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure that Scanner is the best tool for this as hasNext(Pattern) checks to see if the next **complete token** has the next pattern.  Your pattern goes across tokens.

Have you tried using a Matcher object instead of the Scanner?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Foo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "DBREF  1A1F A  102    190  UNP     P08046    EGR1_MOUSE      308     396";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+[a-zA-Z]\\s+\\d{1,}\\s+\\d{1,}\\s+");

        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(line);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.printf("group: %s%n", matcher.group());
        }
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working.. i think problem is with pattern.compile arguments

Comment: They worked fine for me.  A little verbose perhaps, but they should work.  Try a small compiled test program such as shown above.

Comment: have u tried with this Line :- DBREF 1A1F A 102 190 UNP P08046 EGR1_MOUSE 308 396

Comment: I've tried with the line posted in my code, and it worked well.  What's happening when you try it?

Comment: I suspect that there's a bug in your program that you're not showing.  Again, create a very small compilable runnable example like I've posted and then post this code in your question as an addition, and let us test your actual code. -- edit: nevermind! :) Glad you have it working!

Answer (score 3):

This regex line works:

```
\\s+\\w\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+
```

`group(0)` of your [matcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) (`p.matcher`) gives `A 102 190`

.

[EDIT] Ok, I'll give you a complete working sample then:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+\\w\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher("DBREF  1A1F A  102   190  UNP    P08046   EGR1_MOUSE     308    396");
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println("Found match: " + matcher.group(0));
    // Found match:  A 102 190
```

Comment: I just tried it, it works. Are you sure you're extracting the first `group` of your matcher?

Comment: have u tried with this Line :- DBREF  1A1F A  102   190  UNP    P08046   EGR1_MOUSE     308    396

Comment: Yes, that works too. I've now given you a full example to illustrate my point.